# Android Service stops working when calling activity is killed or destroyed

Tags: java, android, android-service

I saw related question and answers on this site but yet to get a satisfactory solution.

My issue is this:

My service uses an object (List of data) from my app.

Example:

```
 public class HelloService extends Service{
      List<POI> poiList = Globalata.getListOfPOI(); //  -- line a
 }
```

This makes the service crash when the activity / app is killed. If I delete (line a) the services keeps running when my app is killed/destroyedI am using started service. What can I do ? Is there a way to keep my service from crashing and stopping when my activity / app is killed ?

Comment: Instead you should parcel/serialize your object and pass that to the service...probably as an extra to the service intent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide me with an example code ? Am checking online also.

Comment: http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

Comment: Why not store the list data in a database ? you would be able to use it from your service any time.

Comment: I have an XML file, I parsed the XML in the main activity, then stored the data in a List. So I have List of the Object. If I do the parsing in the Service, I can get the list but won't that affect the service ?

Comment: I parsed the XML file in the service. It works though not an optimized solution in my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the list and probably it's objects on a private one on the service.
So the service will have it's own copy when the activity is killed.

By the way, avoir using static access as much as you can, but it depend on you are app.